# Passing values to a map function - CouchDB

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchdb, map-function, nosql

I was wondering whether its possible to pass values to a map function in couchDB design document.

**For Example:**

In the code below is it possible to pass a value that has been entered by the user and use that value to run the map function. Maybe I can pass users **UserName** when they login and then display the view based on the map function.

```
function(doc) {
   if(doc.name == data-Entered-By-User) {
   emit(doc.type, doc);
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance.
Regards

Comment: Check out the [docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/views/index.html) about how views work. The short answer is _no_, but I think you need to read up more about how CouchDB (and it's views) work.

Answer (score 5):

This is a common mistake in CouchDB when using views. It's kinda confusing, but instead of this:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.value === 'thing I am looking for') {
    emit(doc.value);
  }
}
```

What you want is this:

```
function (doc) {
  emit(doc.value);
}
```

And then when you query, you do:

```
/mydb/_design/myddoc/_view/myview?key="thing I am looking for"
```

You might want to read my [12 pro tips for better code with PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/2014/06/17/12-pro-tips-for-better-code-with-pouchdb.html), especially tip #9. The tips apply equally well to CouchDB. :)