# how to pass url params to couchdb map function

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I have this map function

```
function (doc) {

// Leidse plein
// this is now fixed, but needs to be dynamic from the url params
center_latitude = 52.3648111;
center_longitude = 4.8810906;

// this is fixed, but also needs to be dynamic from the url params
radius  = 5;

// calc distance between centerpoint and userpoint
distance = Math.acos(
  Math.sin(doc.latitude * Math.PI / 180) * 
  Math.sin(center_latitude * Math.PI / 180) 
  + 
  Math.cos(doc.latitude * Math.PI / 180) * 
  Math.cos(center_latitude * Math.PI / 180) * 
  Math.cos((doc.longitude - center_longitude) * Math.PI / 180)) * 6371;

  // all poi's within 5km radius
  if(distance <= radius ) {
      emit([doc.title,doc.latitude,doc.longitude], distance);
  }

 }
```

So this works, but I need to have it dynamic so I can pass the center_longitude and center_latitude from the url params. I'm still new in CouchDB. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works works, you'd "accept" the answer, more here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) . But only if your question really has been answered. If not, consider adding more details to the question.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to have parameters in a map function.

I point you to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572449/passing-values-to-a-map-function-couchdb) but it is not applicable in your case.

The [list functions](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/ddocs/ddocs.html#list-functions) or [filter functions](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/ddocs/ddocs.html#filter-functions) can receive url parameters but you'll have some performance problems if the number of documents in the database grow as the complete db need to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use CouchDB for geo-spatial information, one idea is to try out [Cloudant Geospatial](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/cloudant-geo.html#cloudant-nosql-db-geospatial). It has many features like being able to query according to `radius`:

Example of a radius query:

```
?lat=-11.05987446&lon=12.28339928&radius=100
```

Example query to find documents that have a geospatial position within a circle:

```
curl -X GET 'https://education.cloudant.com/crimes/_design/geodd/_geo/geoidx?lat=42.3397&lon=-71.07959&radius=10&relation=contains&format=geojson'
```

There are detailed descriptions on [Cloudant geo documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/cloudant-geo.html#cloudant-nosql-db-geospatial).